# Good UI library / script to browse a web site using a graph?

Tags: graph, navigation, web-scraping

I'm creating a set of web pages. I'd like to use a graph (visual nodes and edges) to navigate this website.

I plan to have a graph (a topic map) created from another software and exported in a suitable format. Each web page will be a node, and I'd like it to be able to display a thumbnail (at least some piece of text) when hovering.

The graph should be force-directed, with pan/zoom capabilities, optionally hyperbolic.
The graph is not a tree, each node may have an edge with any other.

I think about something in Javascript/Php/Java/Silverlight, but this is not a final choice.

Comment: Hey 'renamed guy', did you find a good solution for this? If so, would you mind sharing which option you went for in the end and/or a link to the implementation, if it's running on a public site somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Protovis javascript visualization library from Stanford[1]. It has force-directed graphs.

An alternative the the Javascript infovis toolkit[2]. Check out the demos.

[1] http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

[2] http://thejit.org/

Comment: Nice suggestions, both impressive and fast with the examples provided. Will require a bit of programming though. Let me read and try them. Thanks a lot. Did you see them in use at some sites for web navigation?